# Where can I find a triple three-way switch for a single-gang box?

Tags: electrical, switch, multiway-switch

I recently bought a house built in the 60s and am updating all the switches to be uniform and rocker type. I have a single gang box with a triple switch where all are 3 way. Does this even exist anywhere? I can't find it online or much information. I believe the old one is called a Despard switch.

What is the best course of action? Do I need to have an electrician separate into multiple gang boxes?

[image]

Comment: That does sound a bit unusual. Turn off the breaker. Unscrew the switch and pull it out *without disconnecting any wires*. Upload pictures showing the wires going into each side of the switch *and* the wires going into the back of the box.

Comment: Double 3-ways are easy to find. Triple singles are easy to find. I found one 2-single + 1-3-way.

Comment: Yes, I have found all those other switches as well. I'm not yet ready to pull it out of the box as I'm worried about not being able to immediately replace and then not being able to get it back into the box

Comment: All three switches are three way switches?

Comment: What does each switch control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's totally illegal to have *that much stuff* in a 1-gang box.

Let's be graceful and assume all three 3-ways are ends of a switch loop. So 9 conductors + 1 allocation for ground + 1 allocation for switch yoke, plus (gracefully) 0 allocations for cable clamps.  That is 12 wire allocations.  Gracefully assume the smallest wire size, so 2.0 cubic inches per allocation = 24 cubic inch box.

Every 3-way *that isn't* the end of a switch loop will have at least 2 more wires I didn't count, possibly even 4.

*Forget about it. Virtually no 1-gang box has that much space even for the "most graceful assumption".  Realistically you will have more wires and they may be #12 with a larger volume demand.*  You would need a crazy-enormous box, like

- A 4x4x2-1/8" box + 1-gang mud ring (35 ci)
- A 4-11/16" square box + 1-gang mud ring (46 ci)

I'm not even slightly surprised that wires are packed so tight in there that you are afraid to pull it out.  *That's illegal*.

Also, those old Despards had a way of getting brittle. Pulling them out, you are likely to snap off some of the critical plastic grooves that allow the latching mechanism to hold the switch into the frame.

Also the switches are different colors for a reason: to help the user identify the light being controlled.

### Despard replacements are *obscure and costly*

Yes, they were a neat modular system, and the *only* option for triple 3-way switches on one yoke.

You will never find a triple 3-way in another format.

The only way you will find Despards for real is [mail order](https://www.kyleswitchplates.com/despard-switches-outlets/)... and all-in, a triple 3-way switch will be over $60, **and this does NOTHING to solve the cubic-inch-in-box problem**.  So you would *still* need a large box like a 4-11/16" with a 1-gang mud ring on it.

Your best bet is to replace with a 3-gang box.  You could do it with a 2-gang box, but I'd strongly recommend the steel 4-11/16" box with a 2-gang mud ring, so you have enough cubic inches.

Comment: "You'll never find a replacement for Despards" Yet here they are [kyleswitchplates.com](https://www.kyleswitchplates.com/despard-switches-outlets/)!

Comment: Wow, @GlenYates, they're even UL listed (as stamped into the switch frame, not just according to the web site)! Unless, of course, that's an unauthorized stamping...

Comment: Look at that. They still don't have three 3 ways though and I'm also updating to rocker style

Comment: @Newbie Yeah, the closest you can get is on the second page, two 3-ways and 1 S/P.

Comment: @Newbie they do have 3-ways, but you'd have to build it yourself with a frame ($4) plus three 3-way switches ($18 each).  All-in, over $60.

Comment: @GlenYates thanks, corrected.  Still doesn't solve the cubic-inch problem though.

Comment: Never seen or heard of these. Wow.   [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1srsFQ5DFo0) video of someone updating his, illustrates this answer nicely.  The box in the video  is bigger than yours and his switches aren't three way, and it's still "congested" to borrow his polite term.

Comment: Update: Removed the switches and the ring cover to discover the box was big enough that we were able to just use a larger cover with the existing box and use a double switch and a single switch side by side. Thankfully much less of a headache than I imagined